# Can I also vote?

Tags: discussion, election

Can anyone please clarify if users like me with low reputation can also vote in the moderator elections?Thank you.

Comment: This means that you have a day or two to gain the remainder of the needed reputation. I doable task by all accounts!

Comment: Well, I do not really think it is possible.But maybe it can be done.I need lots of upvotes and stuff.

Comment: You need eight votes on answers or 16 votes on questions. If you write three-four decent answers you should garner at least eight votes. In two or three days? That is completely doable in my opinion.

Comment: Hopefully, it will materialize. Thanks for that info.

Comment: Correction: You have **nine** days. Even if you get one vote per day you can still catch the last day.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila You were right.I reached it.It's 159 as I type. :)

Comment: @AmitabhUdayiman: Ask a question on $\pi$ or $e$ -- it always works. ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [moderator election format and design](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1212/community-moderator-election-format-and-design) thread:

"Any user in good standing with 150 reputation may vote in the primary."

The same threshold applies to the election phase.